YQ - how to filter an array by field value if matching at least one element in a list
Specifically (https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) 4.35+
I have a comma-separated string of terms and I want to filter down a list if a field value is one of those terms.
Ex) Given the following input:
- name: bob
  age: 12
- name: jen
  age: 22
- name: mork
  age: 4003

Include elements whose name field value exists as a substring of "jen,mork" such that the output is:
- name: jen
  age: 22
- name: mork
  age: 4003

I can also represent the terms as a string array, i.e. ["jen", "mork"]
So the equivalent of something like:
yq 'filter("jen,mork" | contains(.name))' array.yaml
# Though I'm not sure how `contains` gets the original array context
# or
yq 'filter(.name in ["jen", "mork"])' array.yaml

I realize this can be done by building an or set, as follows:
yq 'filter(.name == "jen" or .name == "mork"])' array.yaml

but I was hoping for something a little more elegant.
I'm not really sure what to try as it seems this is backwards to how the operators want to work.

Simply construct a stream, and the comparison will automatically iterate over its items:
yq 'filter(.name == ("jen", "mork"))' array.yaml

To import the list, use an environment variable, and env to access it:
list='["jen", "mork"]' yq 'filter(.name == (env(list) | .[]))' array.yaml

With yq v4.44.2, you can shorten to .name == env(list)[].
Output:
- name: jen
  age: 22
- name: mork
  age: 4003


Thank you so much! I figured it was a simple solution, but I couldn't find anything in the documentation... and I still can't. This is what comes up when searching for "stream" in the docs: https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/usage/tips-and-tricks#reading-multiple-streams-stdins.
If you know where this discussed in the docs, please leave a link to it. Thanks again!

The wording was actually jq terminology (which mikefarah/yq is inspired by), but even there the term is ambiguous. Check out their docs on the comma operator and the yq docs on the union operator.
